# How to pass a custom field to CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, express-checkout, paypal-nvp

All is in the title, I tried a lot of possibilities but I didn't find a way to do this. My goal is to get some data in IPN allowing me to know which offer the user choose.

I know how to do it with SetExpressCheckout and it works in express_checkout context... but when in recurring_payment_profile_created or recurring_payment context, I'm not able to pass any custom field.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the custom field of BillingAgreement is ignored for CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile, I don't understand why but I decide to use the ProfileReference field as suggested here: [PAYPAL IPN custom field missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702419/paypal-ipn-custom-field-missing?rq=1)